# How to find occurrences of values in a different column in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `pandas` DataFrame `df` that portrays edges of a directed acyclic graph, sorted by `Target`:

```
Source       Target
C            A
D            A
A            B
C            B
D            B
E            B
E            C
C            D
E            D
```

I would like to add a column `Weight` based on occurrences of values.

`Weight` should illustrate the number of appearance of the `Target` value in `Target` divided by the number of appearance of the `Source` value in `Target`.

In other words, the first row of the example should have the `Weight` of 2/1 = 2, since `A` appears twice in `Target` where `C` appears only once in `Target`.

I have first tried

`df.apply(pd.Series.value_counts)`

but the problem is my actual DataFrame is extremely large, so I am not able to manually search for each occurrence value from the outcome and make a quotient. I have also tried to write two new columns that signify the values I need, then to write a final column that consists of what I want:

```
df['tfreq'] = df.groupby('Target')['Target'].transform('count')
df['sfreq'] = df.groupby('Source')['Target'].transform('count')
```

but it seems like my second line of code returns the occurrences of `Source` values in `Source` column instead of `Target` column.

Are there any insights on this problem?

Comment: I think you need pd.crosstab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `value_counts` with `map`. Then divide them:

```
val_counts = df['Target'].value_counts()

counts1 = df['Target'].map(val_counts)
counts2 = df['Source'].map(val_counts)

df['Weights'] = counts1.div(counts2) # same as counts1 / counts2
```

**Output**

```
  Source Target  Weights
0      C      A      2.0
1      D      A      1.0
2      A      B      2.0
3      C      B      4.0
4      D      B      2.0
5      E      B      NaN
6      E      C      NaN
7      C      D      2.0
8      E      D      NaN
```

*note*: we get `NaN` because `E` does not occur in column `Target`